# How to calculate Time Complexity for a given algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

i, j, N, sum is all integer type. N is input.

( Code1 )

```
i = N;

while(i > 1)
{
    i = i / 2;
    for (j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
    {
       sum = sum + j;
    }
}
```

( Code2 )

```
sum = 0;
d = 1;
d = d << (N-1);
for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
}
```

How to calculate step count and time complexity for a Code1, Code2?

Comment: SO isn't a homework forum, use your text, or previously posted questions

Comment: @SGM1 Sorry. but it isn't homework. I study algorithm. it's self study.

Comment: @SGM1 In addition it's not homework question. I just think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to calculate the time complexity try to understand what takes how much time, and by what `n` are you calculating.

if we say the addition ("+") takes O(1) steps then we can check how many time it is done in means of `N`.

the first code is dividing `i` in 2 each step, meaning it is doing log(N) steps. so the time complexity is

```
 O(log(N) * 1000000)= O(log(N))
```

the second code is going form 0 to 2 in the power of n-1 so the complexity is:

```
 O(s^(N-1) * 1000000)=  O(2^(N-1))
```

but this is just a theory, because d has a max of 2^32/2^64 or other number, so it might not be O(2^(N-1)) in practice

Comment: I have one question. d = d << (N-1); code's step is 2 ^ (n-1)?

Comment: depend on the d. if d=1 then yes, if d=2 then it's 2^n and so on

Comment: I Understand that now. :)

Comment: @iSangyoon glad to be of service